# White noise, stochastic convolution: $0$–$1$ law of a stopping time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Let $\mathscr{C}^\alpha:=B_{\infty,\infty}^{\alpha}$ be the Besov space with the usual norm and let $C_T\mathscr{C}^\alpha:=C([0,T],\mathscr{C}^\alpha)$ the space of continuous functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathscr{C}^\alpha$ with the usual supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{C_T\mathscr{C}^\alpha}$.

Let $\xi$ be a space-time white noise and $Y(r):=\int_{0}^rP_{r-q}\xi(q)dq,$ (we are taking $Y \in C_T\mathscr{C}^\alpha$ for every $T>0$), $(P_r)_{r \geq 0}$ is the semi-group generated by $\Delta.$

Consider the stopping time $\theta:=\inf\{r \in \mathbb{R}_+,\sqrt{r}\Vert Y\Vert_{C_r\mathscr{C}^\alpha}>\frac{2}{3}\}.$

Is it true that $P(\theta =\infty) \in \{0,1\}$?